# Why notate the solution to steady-state heat equation as $2\Phi$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, physics, heat-equation

In literature I read the following:

[image]

Based on what is said, I think that to obtain Eqn(3) one substitutes Eqn(1.17(1)) into the heat equantion, Eqn(B), and then consider the steady-state condition, $\partial v/\partial t=0$, leading to Eqn(C):
$$\tag{1.17(1)} f_i=-K_{ij} \frac{\partial v}{\partial x_j}$$
$$\tag{B} \rho c \frac{\partial v}{\partial t}+\left(\frac{\partial f_x}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial f_y}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial f_z}{\partial z}\right)=0$$
$$\tag{C} K_{ij}\frac{\partial ^2 v}{\partial x_i \partial x_j}=0$$
In deriving Eqn(C) the $K_{ij}$ are constants, and thus are pulled from the derivative. **So my question is this:** if I correctly derived Eqn(C), and I am correct that it is equivalent to Eqn(3), why then would the authors equate Eqn(3) to $2\Phi$ instead of $0$?

I note that I have not seen the variable $\Phi$ used/defined in this text leading up to this section (Sec. 1.20), nor have I seen it used after.

Some thoughts to consider:

1. The 2nd-rank tensor $K_{ij}$ is usually taken as symmetric,
   $K_{ij}=K_{ji}$. Under this assumption the right-hand side of Eqn(3) may be written as $$K_{11}\partial_{xx}^2v+K_{22}\partial_{yy}^2v+K_{33}\partial_{zz}^2v+2K_{23}\partial_{yz}^2v+2K_{13}\partial_{xz}^2v+2K_{12}\partial_{xy}^2v \tag{D}$$
2. The scalar magnitude $K$ of the symmetric positive-definite 2nd-rank tensor $K_{ij}$ is $$K=K_{ij}l_il_j=K_{11}l_1^2+K_{22}l_2^2+K_{33}l_3^2+2K_{23}l_2l_3+2K_{13}l_1l_3+2K_{12}l_1l_2 \tag{E}$$ where $l_i$ is a unit vector in the direction in which $K$ is evaluated. So perhaps in some way $2\Phi$ is related to the scalar magnitude of $K_{ij}$?

Comment: Hard to say what is really meant without knowing what $\Phi$ itself is supposed to mean. But in general this reminds me of the various floating factors of $2$ that appear in the relationship between PDE diffusion and stochastic diffusion.

Comment: @Ian I added some thoughts at end of post. The first might pertain to why there is a factor of 2. Curious to know what you think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notation is a bit unusual, using $v$ for temperature, but they probably use $T$ for something else.  If you start with the steady-state heat equation:
$$-\nabla \cdot (K \nabla v)=Q$$

with a heat coefficient tensor $K$ (or you can choose to see it as a matrix) and source term $Q$. So the heat equation is not necessarily equal to zero since you can have a source term.

For anisotropic materials, I think some authors write the left-hand side of the heat equation as:
$$-\frac{1}{2}\nabla \cdot (K \nabla v)-\frac{1}{2}\nabla \cdot (K^T \nabla v)=$$
$$=-\nabla \cdot (\frac{1}{2}(K+K^T) \nabla v)$$
If the diffusion tensor/matrix $K$ is symmetric, which it usually is, then you get:
$$\frac{1}{2}(K+K^T)=K$$

Maybe the author has written:
$$-\frac{1}{2}\nabla \cdot (K \nabla v)-\frac{1}{2}\nabla \cdot (K^T \nabla v)=Q$$

If we now define: $$\Phi=\frac{1}{2}\nabla \cdot (K \nabla v)$$
we get the heat equation as:
$$-2\Phi=Q$$

This is a highly unusual way of writing things but it is my best guess.

Comment: This is from the seminal text Conduction of Heat in Solids by Carslaw and Jaeger (1959, 2nd Ed.)

Comment: I see. Thanks for letting me know @armadillo.

Comment: According to the sentence right after Eqn(3), we have $-2\Phi=Q=f_m(\partial v/\partial m)$. Would that make sense?

Comment: Yes, that seems right @Armadillo.

Comment: I read the book and the notation $2 \Phi$ is indeed not explained$

Comment: In your derivation, we assume $K$ to be symmetric and therefore $\Phi=\frac{1}{2}\nabla \cdot (K \nabla v)=\frac{1}{2}\nabla \cdot (K^T \nabla v)$?

Comment: @Armadillo yes, correct.

Comment: Nowhere in the derivation from Eqn(1) to (3), nor anywhere else in the book from what I can tell, do the authors state they are considering steady-state flow. I just assumed that was the case when post this question. Would their, and your, derivation still be valid if the non-steady-state equation was used (with or without the source term)? $$-\nabla \cdot (K \nabla v)=\alpha \partial_t v$$

Comment: @armadillo Yes, this is fine even for the transient case. The coefficient $\alpha$ in your equation and $K$ are independent.